# How do I fix this libgcrypt cross-compilation error?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, imx6, libgcrypt

I'm trying to cross compile GPG for an ElinOS on a board with an imx6. I have a problem when I compile libgcrypt. First, here's what I do:

```
export PATH=/opt/elinos/cdk/arm/v7hf/glibc/bin:$PATH 
./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu 
make all
```

The configuration part shows no errors or warning, but the make displays this:

```
hwf-arm.c:31:3: error: #error Module build for wrong CPU.
 # error Module build for wrong CPU.
   ^
hwf-arm.c: In function 'get_hwcap':
hwf-arm.c:126:26: error: 'AT_HWCAP' undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (auxv.a_type == AT_HWCAP)
                          ^
hwf-arm.c:126:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
hwf-arm.c:132:26: error: 'AT_HWCAP2' undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (auxv.a_type == AT_HWCAP2)
                          ^
In file included from hwf-arm.c:27:0:
hwf-arm.c: In function 'detect_arm_at_hwcap':
hwf-arm.c:159:23: error: 'arm_features' undeclared (first use in this function)
   for (i = 0; i < DIM(arm_features); i++)
                       ^
g10lib.h:96:24: note: in definition of macro 'DIM'
 #define DIM(v) (sizeof(v)/sizeof((v)[0]))
                        ^
hwf-arm.c: In function 'detect_arm_proc_cpuinfo':
hwf-arm.c:250:23: error: 'arm_features' undeclared (first use in this function)
   for (i = 0; i < DIM(arm_features); i++)
                       ^
g10lib.h:96:24: note: in definition of macro 'DIM'
 #define DIM(v) (sizeof(v)/sizeof((v)[0]))
```

The first error leads me to this part of the code :

```
#if !defined (__arm__) && !defined (__aarch64__)
# error Module build for wrong CPU.
#endif
```

Any idea where this comes from? It looks like a configuration problem, but I'm not sure where to look now.

Comment: `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` and `i686-pc-linux-gnu ` don't look compatible. Can you post the output of `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf  -E -P -v -dD - </dev/null`?

Comment: [Here is the output for the gcc version](http://batman.gyptis.org/zerobin/?00701ee46d551949#Wsh1NVlxI5TIJXfLb+9m37sTLhIDqmvcWDhIJ0rwznU=). I can see `Configured with: [...] --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu` in it.

Comment: You should check your `config.log` to ensure the environment is what you expect. You should also specify `CC` and a `--sysroot`. `CC` is probably using the host's gcc instead of `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` (or whatever it is called).  `--sysroot` tells libgcrypt build where to find ARM headers and libraries. You may need to specify `AR`, `LD` and some other friends, too.

Comment: Adding CC solved the problem. Should I answer my own question with this?

Comment: Go ahead an answer. If possible, show how you detected the wrong compiler was being used, like something from `config.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `config.log` file, CC was setup correctly: `CC='arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'`.

Yet I needed to specify it in the make command. So instead of simply using `make all`, which didn't work, I had to use `make all CC=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.